# Using excel VBA to fill in a handsontable

Tags: excel, vba, handsontable

I had built and excel sheet that filled out repetitive data on a web page for work. We've recently updated the page to using a javascript table called a hands on table and this broke my macro. I've been trying to find a way to modify the macro to fill in the hands on table but I cant interact with this javascript table.

When I look on my sites page its just a div whit an ID and when I try and select something in I just over write the table.

```html
                <div id="qty" class="handsontable" style="width:100%">
                </div>
```

Below is a hands on table demo, very similar to what we are using. Does anyone have any ideas?

https://handsontable.com/examples?headers

Thank you.

Comment: Use *right click >> Inspect* not *view Page Source*

Comment: You can also press F12 and click through the DOM tree in the HTML inspector.